# Что не так в этом классе, есть ошибка

Tags: php

Есть вот такой кусочек кода, меня спрашивают что не так, а я не понимаю. Будьте добры, объясните мне что не так? :)

```php
class SomeClass
{
    protected $_someMember;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->_someMember = 1;
    }
    public static function getSomethingStatic()
    {
        return $this->_someMember * 5;
    }
}
```

Comment: Это же тест. задание )) Ай-йа-йай!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В статическом методе нельзя использовать объекты

```
public static function getSomethingStatic()
{
    return $this->_someMember * 5;
}
```

`$this` является в контексте объекта

Answer (score 0):

```
class SomeClass
{
    protected static $_someMember;

    public function __construct()
    {
        self::$someMember = 1;
    }
    public static function getSomethingStatic()
    {
        return self::$someMember * 5;
    }
}
```

---

В таком классе не будет ошибки, но то ли это, что тебе нужно.